# Mapstruct check null

Tags: java, mapstruct

I wand check check null in method

```
@Override
 public void updateFooFromNonNullAttributesOfDto(FooDto fooDto, Foo foo) {
        if ( fooDto== null ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( fooDto.getBar() != null ) {
            site.setBar( fooDto.getBar() );
        }
         if ( fooDto.getBaz() != null ) {
            site.setBar( fooDto.getBaz() );
        }
}
```

When I use

```
@Mapper( NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS)
```

It's check in all methods, but I want check only in one...
How to solve this problem?

Comment: May be you can use `@Nullable/@NotNull` annotations at the method declarations.

Comment: MapStruct does not have support for those annotations yet see [#1243](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1243)

Comment: The above method looks like a candidate for an `@AfterMapping` method in the mapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not yet possible with MapStruct, you can either do for all or for none. There is already a feature request for the exact same thing. See [1243](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1243)

Comment: how to prevent it for all ? No null check at all ?

Comment: That is the default value. `NullValueCheckStrategy.ON_IMPLICIT_CONVERSION`

Answer (score 1):

You could annotade your mapping function with a conditionExpression

```
<i>@Mapping(source="bar", target="bar", conditionExpression = "java(fooDto.getBar()!=null)")</i>
```

Comment: But, that's what MapStruct will do by default ..

Comment: You are right, so the original question is now the standard behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some custom Ignore startegy.

Source of discussion :[link][1]

Possible values for ignoreStrategy:

```
ALWAYS (as true)
NEVER (as false)
NULL_SOURCE (ignore if source value is null) - often required in many projects
    if (source.getValue() != null)
        target.setValue (source.getValue());
NULL_TARGET (ignore if target value is null)
    if (target.getValue() != null)
        target.setValue(source.getValue());
```

[1]: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/369 ???

Bug? I can modify the other's answer????

Comment: I see this article (it's very old), but can't understand how use ignoreStrategy

Comment: That part is not implemented yet, it is just a feature request

Answer (score 0):

According to your example, you give `fooDto.getBaz()` precedence over `fooDto.getBar()`. You could realise this in the Mapper-Interface like:

```java
/*
 * regular mapping FooDto.bar to Foo.bar
 */
Foo map(FooDto fooDto);

/*
 * Overwrite Foo.bar by FooDto.baz if present
 */
@AfterMapping
default updateFooFromNonNullAttributesOfDto(FooDto fooDto, Foo foo) {
  if (fooDto== null ) {
    return;
  }
  if(fooDto.getBaz() != null) {
   foo.setBar(fooDto.getBaz());
  }
}
```